Pulumi - Java - Unifi Provider
I'am wondering if Pulumi supports the unifi Provider with JAVA properly.
There are Java examples in the Pulumi registry - Pulumi Registry Unifi.
Unfortunately there is no specific unifi maven dependency on Maven Central - Maven Central Search Pulumi, Unifi
Is there another place for the Java Artifact?
Thanks for your help!
Dependency in "pom.xml" contains only basic pulumi java classes.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pulumi</groupId>
        <artifactId>pulumi</artifactId>
        <version>0.16.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

In the meantime i found additional informations about this topic, the pulumi-unifi provider is managed throught pulumiuniverse by the community and there is no published java sdk pulumiverse issue 44.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The Unifi provider is a community provider and not managed by Pulumi Corp.
The Pulumiverse community still hasn't support for publishing the Java SDKs for the providers it maintains. The actual status of this can be followed in this community issue:
https://github.com/pulumiverse/infra/issues/44
Hope this at least helps with explaining why there is no Java support at the moment.
